# HTACCESS subdomain and environment ZEND

Tags: zend-framework, parameters, subdomain

We're currently creating an application with ZEND that we'd like to be able to set the environments through a second parameter IN FRONT of the domain.

Something like this:

```
app.production.mysite.com
```

App would indicate the folder (mysite.com/app), production the environment and mysite our domain.

Comment: What have you tried? The environment part would be easy, but what do you mean by "app would indicate the folder"?

Comment: Well, the APP should direct to the folder APP as a normal sub domain does (app.mysite.com = mysite.com/app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apache2 aliases together with mod_rewrite rules in order to achieve that.

This is an example httpd.conf section which setup a root zend framework app in `/var/rootapp`, and 2 other separated ZF apps under `app1` & `app2` folders.

```
<Directory "/var/app1/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /app1
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/app2/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /app2
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</Directory>



<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.production.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/rootapp/public

  Alias /app1 /var/app1/public
  Alias /app2 /var/app1/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, Does this mean that I need to edit the HTTPD.CONF in order to achieve this? Isn't there a HTACCESS only way?

Comment: i don't believe so. the Alias command is defined in the VirtualHost, which isn't configurable using .htaccess